# How to create your own properties for element in SilverLight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Can someone help me with this question?) In My XAML I have Listbox element. I want to add my user property into it(in my case - ConnectorStyle)

**My XAML code:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource CanvasItemsPanelTemplate}" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodePictureTemplate}" 
               ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CanvasItemStyle}" 
                ConnectorStyle="{StaticResource ConnectorLineStyle}"/>
```

**In my Model I have prepared this property:**

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectorStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                           "ConnectorStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(NodePicture), null);
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

                    }
        public Style ConnectorStyle
        {
            get { return (Style)GetValue(ConnectorStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ConnectorStyleProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

**But I is a mistake - Cannot resolve ConnectorStyle.
Is there a simple (or a right way ) way of doing this?**

Comment: I think it may be important to mention that the code you show here is technically speaking not your model, it is the code of your UserControl class named "MainPage", so even if it is C# code, this is still your view. The model (or viewmodel) would be where "Nodes" lives: that is, the class you are binding to. I only mention it because this may help clarify why the property you created is not visible to the ListBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: Either you can write a subclass for the ListBox that adds the DependencyProperty or you can write an attached property.

In your case you probably want to write a subclass that adds the property. Try something like this:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox 
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectorStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ConnectorStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MyListBox), null);
    public Style ConnectorStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(ConnectorStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConnectorStyleProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

This will add a new type of ListBox that you can add in your xaml code. It will have all the same properties as a regular ListBox, but it will also have the ConnectorStyle property.

If you need to respond to changes to the ConnectorStyle property in your listbox then you should change the code for the Dependency Property, but that is outside the scope of this question.

And in XAML it shoul be :

```
<local:ListBoxEx 
             ConnectorStyle="{StaticResource ConnectorLineStyle}"/>
```

Comment: thanks, @Rune Grimstad, but there is some updating in your answer

Comment: There was an error in the code. It had an incorrect return type for the property. Fixed now.